# Получить CID, MCC, MNC, LAC

Tags: java, python

Для реализации приложения требуется получить GSM Cell ID, к которой подключено устройство, приложение не нуждается в мощном интерфейсе, поэтому хотелось бы написать на Python/Kivy, если такой возможности нет, то напишу на Java. Подскажите какие библиотеки можно взять для определения GSM Cell ID?

Comment: А на чем вы все это запускать хотите? Из-под линуха с получением данных с сотового модема или как?

Comment: Планирую под Android, в идеале в качестве демона, чтобы мог лишь нотификации отправлять в центр уведомлений

Answer (score 1):

Далеко не всякий GSM модуль отдает всю нужную информацию. Даже стандартные средства  Android SDK на разных устройствах не всегда все корректно отдают.
Посмотрите [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html)
А вообще самый лучший вариант - root и работа с GSM модулем через АТ команды.